# Nginx fastcgi buffers

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

Добрый день всем!

Согласно документации NGINX http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffers

> fastcgi_buffers число размер; Задаёт число и размер буферов для одного
>   соединения, в которые будет читаться ответ, получаемый от
>   FastCGI-сервера.

Если я выделил:
fastcgi_buffers 100 32k;

А ответ php-fpm был 500 kb, значит ли это что для него выделится область ram равная 3200 kb?

Благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Игорь Сысоев:

> Нет, для ответа выделится максимум 16 буферов по 32K (500 / 32 =
>   15.625).